# How to position the list view Thumbnails to the right in jQuery mobile 1.4.0?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a list view  in my jQuery mobile app. I need to position the Thumbnails to the right I have used the following code in my css file but it didn't work  for jQuery mobile 1.4.0 ? is .ui-li-thumb class deprecated in jQuery mobile 1.4.0 ? how can i do that ? please help me ..

```
<ul data-role="listview"  data-inset="true"  data-filter="true" data-filter-   placeholder="Search  " 
data-split-icon="delete"  style="margin-top: 40px;"  > 

 <li class="RTLList" > <img src="img/thumb" /> element </li>
</ul>
```

Css

```
  .RTLList .ui-li .ui-btn-text .ui-link-inherit .ui-li-thumb  {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 0 !important;

}
```

I have tried also , but it didnt work for me !!

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb .ui-li-thumb {
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    text-align:right;
   float:right;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6b7QW/)**

```
.ui-listview>.ui-li-static.ui-li-has-thumb {
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 6.25em;
}
.ui-listview .ui-li-has-thumb>img:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
}
.ui-listview>li.ui-first-child img:first-child:not(.ui-li-icon){
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
.ui-listview>li.ui-last-child img:first-child:not(.ui-li-icon){
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

The CSS puts the LI padding on the right instead of left and then absolutely positions the thumbnail to the right.

Comment: @ezankerThanks for helping me I tried it but it didn't work !! I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.0 , why do you use this symbol > after  .ui-listview ??

Comment: @ezankerCan you help me please ? its work on jQuery mobile 1.3.2 but not working on the version that I use which is 1.4.0

Comment: The demo fiddle uses jQM 1.4 and works fine, did you go to the link? In CSS > means find the direct child of object. I used the exact CSS from jQM 1.4 and changed the appropriate attributes.

Comment: @ezankerThis is my result http://jsfiddle.net/6b7QW/3/   I have tried to solve it but it didn't work for me , can you help me please ?

Comment: I am sorry , when i have posted my question , I forget the anchor element

Comment: @ezankerYes Thanks a lot , can i make the split line which is at the left of the element word transparent ?? How ?

Comment: @ezankerPlease Can you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076403/list-view-li-elemnt-height-is-less-than-its-thumbnail-height-in-jquery-mobile-1 I have tried many things to solve it but i failed :(

Comment: I put an answer there for you.